# Own mock of JPA repository in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mocking

At the beginning i want to admit that i am aware of mockito, EasyMock etc existing.

How can i test my database with OWN mock.

```
@Entity
public class CLASS{
    private Long id;

    ***constructors/getters/setters****    
}
```

-

```
public interface CLASSrepo extends JpaRepository<CLASS, Long> {
}
```

-

```
@Service
public class CLASSservice {

    @Autowired
    CLASSrepo classRepo;
}
```

Any options how to create own mock without using Mockito @MockBean @Mock etc  and test service with repo mock?

Comment: Sure - create a mock class of your own that implements that interface and inject it into your service.

Comment: mock of Entity with implements repository and than @Inject to service this entity ? 
Ive tried create another service which implements interface but then its required to make it abstract. How to deal with it

Comment: Implement all the methods in the interface.  That's Java 101.

Comment: Then can you give me advice how to deal with methods 
    @Override
    public <S extends T> List<S> saveAll(Iterable<S> iterable) {
        return null;
    }

Comment: You'll need concrete types, of course.  No generics in your mocks.